# where to redirect after accepting invitation in facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is my facebook api Link
http://apps.facebook.com/htglive/

in this application when i send invitation to my friend. It send request but when friend click on it(request) that time redirect url show like this

[https://apps.facebook.com/htglive/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=356816584398026%2C150839391720726%2C313437008754266%2C395992020455270%2C428852643833721%2C359378767471403%2C149260881879612%2C107559709394101%2C493997430629776%2C461324317231628%2C271738296259177%2C503347039680580&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request#!/htglive/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=356816584398026%2C150839391720726%2C313437008754266%2C395992020455270%2C428852643833721%2C359378767471403%2C149260881879612%2C107559709394101%2C493997430629776%2C461324317231628%2C271738296259177%2C503347039680580%2C416067418450498%2C135051036639910&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request](https://apps.facebook.com/htglive/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=356816584398026,150839391720726,313437008754266,395992020455270,428852643833721,359378767471403,149260881879612,107559709394101,493997430629776,461324317231628,271738296259177,503347039680580&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request#!/htglive/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=356816584398026,150839391720726,313437008754266,395992020455270,428852643833721,359378767471403,149260881879612,107559709394101,493997430629776,461324317231628,271738296259177,503347039680580,416067418450498,135051036639910&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request)

and not happen any thing.
what i can do pleases help to out of this

**Code Here**

```
    FB.init({
        appId: '334798996610530',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        oauth: true
    });

    function inviteFriends() {
        FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Check out this application!',
        title: 'Send your friends an application request',
        },
    function (response) {
        alert(response.to);
    });

}
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, I Need implement almost same, Can you help me for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking *us* what to do after a user accepts an app request send by/through *you* …? You’re funny.

*You* had the request sent, so *you* should know how to react to it resp. what to display/offer to the user.

When the user accepts an app request, they are redirected to your app’s canvas page, and you get the request id(s) passed as a parameter. With that, you can look up the request’s details via the Graph API, and then you should be able to decide what to present to the user.

There’s basically two ways for you to decide what the request was actually “for”:

- you can either save the request id you get back when sending the request to your database, and attach additional info to it; or
- you can use the `data` parameter when making the request to place up to 255 characters of information, that will be stored by Facebook and can retrieved back from the API by you.

Please read the docs, for the basics (which you don’t seem to know much about as of yet), and also for additional details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

(And don’t forget, that *deleting* requests after they been accepted is your responsibility as well.)